# Password doesn't hash before being saved into the db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing an app using Node.js, Mongoose, MongoDb, Express.

I'm trying to hash the password before being saved in the db when the user register, but it doesn't seems to work. The password is saved without hashing, any suggestions?

```
'use strict'

  let mongoose = require('mongoose')
  let bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema

    var userSchema = Schema({
     name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
     password: { type: String, required: true },
     createdAt: {
     type: Date,
     require: true,
     default: Date.now
    }
   })
   // check if user already exists
   userSchema.path('name').validate(function (name) {
   User.findOne({name}, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
  console.log('error')
  } if (user) {
  console.log('The user already exists')
    console.log(user)
  }
  })
}, 'The user already exists')

  // password validation

userSchema.path('password').validate(function (password) {
 return password.length >= 6
 }, 'The password must be of minimum length 6 characters.')
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

 // hashing and adding salt pre save()

   userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function (err, salt) {
    if (err) {
     return next(err)
     }
    bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, null, function (err, hash) {
     // Store hash in your password DB.
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }
       // set the password to the hash
      this.password = hash
    })
    next()
 })
 })
  module.exports = User
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you do `next()` before `bcrypt.hash` callback is called. Move `next()` into `bcrypt.hash` callback.

```
 userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {

        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        }

        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
            // Store hash in your password DB.
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            }
            // set the password to the hash
            this.password = hash
            next()
        })

    })
})
```

Comment: I moved it nothing happened! is there something else I should do ? require it in server.js maybe?

Comment: Yes try moving `var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)` exactly above `module.exports = User` and below `userSchema.pre(...`

Answer (score 2):

`next()` should be called within `bcrypt.hash()` method when using callbacks.

For synchronous:

```
userSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
   const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10)
   const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, salt)

   this.password = hash
   next()
})
```